# JigoShop Cart Button not Working

Tags: wordpress, jigoshop

I'm had to change my wordpress site that is using jigoshop toan other host company and every thing works fine except my cart button. On my old host when I clicked on the button it opens and shows the list of products in my basket, but now the button does not do anything.

My Jigoshop information:

```
Jigoshop Version:         1.8
WordPress Version:        3.9.9

Platform:                 Windows 
Browser Name:             Chrome  
Browser Version:          47.0.2526.80 
User Agent String:        Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW 
                              64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, l
                              ike Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 S
                              afari/537.36

PHP Version:              5.4.45
MySQL Version:            5.5.46-cll
Web Server Info:          Apache
```

does any one why this happend and how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Your WordPress and Jigoshop versions are both way out of date. You should update them.

Comment: Done All up to date, but it was a js file that was causing problemas. Thank You.